# Создание строки размером количества символов в буфере ввода - C++

Tags: c++, c

Хочу реализовать создание строки любого размера, то есть не создавать константу, в зачастую:

```
const int max_size_str = 256;
```

а считать кол-во символов, с буфера ввода, введённых до '\n' + 1 (для \0) и записать как размер строки, чтобы можно было задавать размер строки количеством введённых символов.

---

Я в курсе как пользоваться динамической памятью.
Привожу пример моего вопроса, я не задаю размер массива символов, я пишу строку с клавиатуры, после чего считается кол-во символов в этой строке и создаётся динамический массив символов, а после с буфера ввода то, что я туда написал(строку) копируется в созданный массив при этом дописывая \0 в конце, чтобы читать как строку.

Comment: В контексте C++ этот вопрос смысла не имеет. Строки в плюсах не имеют фиксированного размера by design. Или вы о чём-то другом?

Comment: Ну динамически выделите память под массив. int i = 0; cin << i; char str = new char[i]; https://prog-cpp.ru/cpp-newdelete/

Comment: Наверное, автор хочет вводить строку без ограничений. Т.е. вводишь `abcdef...`, и по мере ввода, размер строки увеличивается.

Comment: Хорошо, а зачем так? Можно ведь просто получшуюсч строку, занести в массив, добавив в конце нулевой байт.

Comment: Мы при создании строки, будь то динамический или статический массив, задаём размер, а потом только вписываем в этот массив символы, после чего ставим вместо '\n'   '\0' так работают функции типа gets_s(строка, размер), а я хочу сначала написать строку, считать её размер и создать массив символов такого размера, потому что если у нас массив изначально всего на 256 элементов, а пользователь вписывает 257 - всё летит

Comment: @BlackKnight, Вам нужно на чистом C или C++?

Comment: Лучше c++, я не использую C функции ввода-вывода

Comment: @BlackKnight, если C++. То можно так: `string s; cin >> s;`.

Comment: Хорошо, давайте тогда с использованием ванильного char и не используя cin, потому что он только до пробела пашет

Comment: @BlackKnight, `std::getline(std::cin, s);`

Comment: Не знал, что стринг так умеет XD.
Я могу показаться дурачком, но прошу привести пример на чистом C, то есть используя массив символов с 0, а не с классом стринг, который ультра крутой и уже всё умеет)

Comment: На чистом C, как ни странно, тоже есть `getline` :) Если её нет под вашей платформой - качайте исходники и делайте аналогично.

Comment: @PinkTux, `getline()` — часть POSIX, а не чистого стандартного С, если что...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, я в курсе. Потому и написал второе предложение, попробуйте прочитать и его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам набросок на C, раз так нужен...

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char * s = malloc(1);
    int  size = 1;
    char c;
    while((c = getc(stdin))!='\n')
    {
        s = realloc(s,size+1);
        s[size-1] = c;
        size++;
    }
    s[size-1] = 0;
    printf("[%s]\n",s);

}
```

Но! писано на коленке, без проверки на ошибки того же `realloc`, крайне неэффективно (постоянное выделение памяти - по одному символу; правильнее - растущий, скажем, в 2 раза буфер).

Так, не более чем для демонстрации идеи.

Comment: В принципе [почти так и есть](https://opensource.apple.com/source/cvs/cvs-19/cvs/lib/getline.c) :-)

Comment: как вариант: http://pcdev.ru/read-line-from-stdin/

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться). И  кстати, я использую вместо 'malloc' 'new', думаю сильно это на функционал влиять не должно

Comment: @BlackKnight, всё-таки хорошо бы определиться: C или C++. Это разные языки. То, что используется new вместо malloc, не означает ровным счётом ничего.

Answer (score 0):

```
 vector<char> v;
copy(istream_iterator<char>(cin), istream_iterator<char>(), back_inserter(v));
// у вас уже есть вектор с таким размером...
```